# How do I set the output directory in selenium during run time?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium with TestNG under Eclipse using Java, and I'd like to know; Is there a way to set the "Output directory" during run time?

I understand that the directory is set in the TestNG properties 
[TestNG Output Dir](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n1dXz.png)

But every time the script runs, it overwrites the log.  I'd like to assign the value of the directory so no matter how many times I execute the script, its output is maintained.

Is it possible to do that?  Or is there another clever method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you executing your test? Are you using batch file for that?

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks for replying.

I create an XML file and then run it by clicking on the "Run" button directly from the Eclipse IDE.